# How to connect sharepoint from android?

Tags: java, android, ios, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a requirement where my client is having all the data in SharePoint. Now the requirement is to bring in all the scenarios with a front end platform - Preferably "Android". Can anyone help in figuring out how to connect SharePoint and get the data using Android.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 3):

To communicate with android you need webservice (API) so by creating API on server side you can consume data from the server.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380.aspx

You can use retrofit or volley in android for network call and get well formed data in android.

Comment: This is the right answer